# AJAX call in Laravel returns Http Exception

Tags: ajax, laravel, httpexception

When I tried to use ajax in laravel it shows the following error,

> { "message": "", "exception":
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException", "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php",
>   "line": 203, "trace": [ { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php",
>   "line": 175, "function": "prepareException", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler", "type": "->" }, {
>   "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\app\Exceptions\Handler.php",
>   "line": 49, "function": "render", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler", "type": "->" }, {
>   "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php",
>   "line": 83, "function": "render", "class": "App\Exceptions\Handler",
>   "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php",
>   "line": 55, "function": "handleException", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline", "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession.php",
>   "line": 49, "function": "Illuminate\Routing\{closure}", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline", "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php",
>   "line": 151, "function": "handle", "class":
>   "Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession", "type": "->"
>   }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php",
>   "line": 53, "function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline", "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession.php",
>   "line": 63, "function": "Illuminate\Routing\{closure}", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline", "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php",
>   "line": 151, "function": "handle", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession", "type": "->" }, {
>   "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php",
>   "line": 53, "function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline", "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php",
>   "line": 37, "function": "Illuminate\Routing\{closure}", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline", "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php",
>   "line": 151, "function": "handle", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse", "type":
>   "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php",
>   "line": 53, "function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline", "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies.php",
>   "line": 59, "function": "Illuminate\Routing\{closure}", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline", "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php",
>   "line": 151, "function": "handle", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies", "type": "->" }, {
>   "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php",
>   "line": 53, "function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline", "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php",
>   "line": 104, "function": "Illuminate\Routing\{closure}", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline", "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php",
>   "line": 667, "function": "then", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline", "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php",
>   "line": 642, "function": "runRouteWithinStack", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Routing\Router", "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php",
>   "line": 608, "function": "runRoute", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Routing\Router", "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php",
>   "line": 597, "function": "dispatchToRoute", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Routing\Router", "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php",
>   "line": 176, "function": "dispatch", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Routing\Router", "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php",
>   "line": 30, "function": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}",
>   "class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel", "type": "->" }, {
>   "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\fideloper\proxy\src\TrustProxies.php",
>   "line": 57, "function": "Illuminate\Routing\{closure}", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline", "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php",
>   "line": 151, "function": "handle", "class":
>   "Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies", "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php",
>   "line": 53, "function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline", "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php",
>   "line": 31, "function": "Illuminate\Routing\{closure}", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline", "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php",
>   "line": 151, "function": "handle", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest", "type":
>   "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php",
>   "line": 53, "function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline", "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php",
>   "line": 31, "function": "Illuminate\Routing\{closure}", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline", "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php",
>   "line": 151, "function": "handle", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest", "type":
>   "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php",
>   "line": 53, "function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline", "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize.php",
>   "line": 27, "function": "Illuminate\Routing\{closure}", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline", "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php",
>   "line": 151, "function": "handle", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize", "type":
>   "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php",
>   "line": 53, "function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline", "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php",
>   "line": 62, "function": "Illuminate\Routing\{closure}", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline", "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php",
>   "line": 151, "function": "handle", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode",
>   "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php",
>   "line": 53, "function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline", "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php",
>   "line": 104, "function": "Illuminate\Routing\{closure}", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline", "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php",
>   "line": 151, "function": "then", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline", "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php",
>   "line": 116, "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter", "class":
>   "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel", "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\public\index.php", "line": 55,
>   "function": "handle", "class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel",
>   "type": "->" }, { "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\TravelAssistant\server.php", "line": 21,
>   "function": "require_once" } ] }

My controller code is,

```
public function getPublicAttraction(Request $request)
    {
        return response(['msg'=>'success']);
    }
```

The ajax call,

```
<script>
    function getAttraction()
    {

        var pass= {'_token':$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')

    };
    $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'{{route("Attractions")}}',
            datatype:'json',
            data: pass,
            success:function(data){
                $("#public_attractions").html(data.msg);
            }
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, error){
            $("#public_attractions").html(jqXHR.responseText);
        });


    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
         getAttraction();
    });
</script>
```

meta tag with csrf token,

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="!!{csrf_token()}!!">
```

the route file web.php entry,

```
Route::post('/getAttractions','AjaxController@getPublicAttraction')->name('Attractions');
```

I think I am stuck, please help.

Comment: Please post your complete error stack trace

Comment: now I've added the complete error stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Why you reinvent something which is working fine.

**1st** Token in blade should look like this: (you have additional !! for what ever reason)

`<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

**2nd** Put this code somewhere in the master blade:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Source https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: Along with that are there any changes in the ajax call ? Is that needed to pass the data '_token ' during the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

Ok, everything looks fine except the way that the CSRF meta tag, Because you don't need to escape anything in the csrf token, so the correct way to print the token will be:

    `<!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

This is the best guess i cant give you, because you do not provide what are the HTTP status of the response, neither which situation the exception is thrown, The exception message is  also empty so ..

Comment: Initially it was like that and generating the same error

Comment: Ok, but , what is the HTTP status of the response?, could be an 401 (Unauthorized)  becouse the "Attractions" route is protected with the "auth" middleware or could be a 500,with a sintax error , or a 419 that could be because is something wrong with the csrf token.

Comment: 1.-Check that the route is not protected with any middleware,
2.-Check what is the Http status of the response (In the developer tools of the browser if you are using the browser).
3.-Check if all the request params are really sent with the request (Browser->Developer tools  -> Network).
Is so much easier if we know the HTTP status , thats says whats is going on in the server side.